# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \, dy \, dx\ $ using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Use polar coordinates to evaluate $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \, dy \, dx\
$

I understand that we need to change $x^2+y^2$ to $r^2$ and then we get $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^{-(r^2)} \, dy \, dx\
$. Then I know I need to change the bounds with respect to $dy$ but I am unsure on how to do that and further. Please help me.

Comment: I am not sure what the extra brackets were - so removed them. Hope all is okay with the edit, so please check. regards

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ and then $dxdy=rdrd\theta$ so

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dydx=\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta=\frac{\pi}{-2\times2}\left[e^{-r^2}\right]_0^1=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1-e^{-1}\right)$$

Comment: This helps a lot thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $y$ goes from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and then $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$. We recognize $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ as the top half of the unit circle with centre the origin.

So our given integral is taken over the first-quadrant part of the unit circle. The variable $r$ will go $0$ to $1$, and $\theta$ will go $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Don't forget to replace $dy\,dx$ by $r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\bullet\;\;\;x=r\cos\theta\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta\;,\;0\le\theta\le \frac\pi2\;\text{(why?). The Jacobian is}\;\;|J|=r$$

So the integral is

$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}re^{-r^2}drd\theta$$

Comment: ${+1}^{{+}{+}{+}{+}{+}{}}$